# How to know suitable pcb package for capacitor in eagle?

Tags: eaglecad

I'm new to eagle soft for designing pcb.
My question is how to know suitable package for capacitor or resistor.
for example I need package for 1000uF,16v CD11x.

Comment: If it isn't in the library you will have to design it yourself. It's quite easy with the Pulsonix software I use.

Comment: Choose your capacitor, look at its datasheet, find a package that fits or make your own footprint

Comment: You select the capacitor you want to use from a distributor website (such as Digikey or Mouser, or even the manufacturer itself). Then look up the datasheet to find the package details. If Eagle doesn't have the footprint already, you'll need to create your own.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are approaching the problem ''backwards'' compared to how most in the industry do it by trying to find a existing footprint. (I'm mainly referring to smaller companies - enterprises with thousands of products sometimes do things differently because they have the volume to warrant it).

You usually want to pick the part (as I think you have done here, and chosen a CD11x series aluminium electrolytic), and then you design the footprint.

Outside of the aforementioned larger companies, most of the time you will end up designing your own footprints. The reason for this is the fact that different boards have different requirements (eg, wave solder, hand solderd and hot-air/oven soldered all require different footprints for the same part), and things like densities also impact the footprint - as a result, the same component will have a different footprint for many boards.

I think most PCB tools (at least I know Altium does) have footprint-generators. These are tools that you can use to quickly generate footprints based on the standards (density, pad shape, etc). In my experience, if I have the datasheet open anyways, it takes far less time to generate a new footprint using the tool, than it does to find one that already exists and then verify it matches my requirements.

Answer (score -1):

> My question is how to know suitable package for capacitor or resistor.

This is something you decide when you select the part.  When you go thru the parametric search on a distributor or manufacturer site, the package is one of the criteria that you choose the device by.  Narrow down on the parts that fit the electrical criteria, then see which package type makes the most sense for your mechanical criteria, price, availability, etc.

> for example I need package for 1000uF,16v CD11x.

First, learn to express values in text properly.  You apparently mean "1000 µF" and "16 V".  Note the space between the numbers and the unit.  Note the "µ", not "u".  Note the upper case "V" for volts.  This is all really basic stuff.  Engineers need to communicate values with units a lot, so this is something where sloppiness is not tolerated.  NIST has a nice document on all this.

In schematics it is often desirable to not have a space between the value and the unit, but we're talking about appearance in ordinary text here, like in your question.

It also helps in being taken seriously if you use engineering notation.  That means you adjust the power of 1000 multiplier so that there are always 1 to 3 digits left of the decimal point.  Your capacitance should therefore be written as "1 mF".  No, others out there being sloppy gives you no excuse to be sloppy yourself.

I have no idea what "CD11x" is supposed to mean.

In any case, once you decide on a specific part, you go to your Eagle (it's a proper noun, note the capital "E", don't be so sloppy) library for that part type, select the suitable device, then select the suitable package variant within that device.

If you don't have such a device in your library, then make one.  If you don't have such a package in your library, then make one.  Neither of those is hard to do.

Comment: It is very rare to see a space before unit on a schematics

Comment: @Maple: True.  I didn't mean this should be followed on schematics where there is often no room and a space might actually cause confusion by making part of the label look like it belongs to something else.  I was referring only to how the OP was expressing units in his text here.  I'll add a note about that to the answer.

Comment: Interesting... apparently SI specifically recommends [space before unit](http://www.npl.co.uk/reference/measurement-units/si-conventions/). Wonder, whom I should hate for countless "hms" after resistance ending with "zero"

Comment: Historically people advised to place the unit as the decimal place - hence the use of e.g. "4k7" instead of "4.7 k" . The argument is that a dot could fade over time with copying (or poor screenshots), whereas the letter would be harder to miss. 
Also, @OlinLathrop, I disagree on your statement "learn to express values in text properly (...) "µ", not "u"". According to ISO 2955, u is a acceptable symbol of micro on systems where the mu symbol may not be easily available.

Comment: And it is common practice to express values of capacitance in uF, even if it is 1000. I agree that 1 mF should be prefered, but it is my opinion that anyone who decides that someone using 1000 uF instead cannot be taken seriously is being overly obtuse.
In fact, if the manufacturer/distributor labels the devices as 1000 uF, I would *advise* to match this (poor) notation, as to avoid any confusion along the line of production etc.

Comment: @Joren: I agree that "u" is acceptable when a mu is not easily available.  However, in HTML it is easily available with "&micro;"